# How to set first "slug" link as active in a php menu

Tags: php, wordpress, gallery

I am working with a Wordpress gallery plugin.

I would like the first link in the filter menu to automatically be active when the page loads. This is as by default it loads ALL the images from all the categories and it's too many! Thanks.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var container = $('#isotope-container').imagesLoaded( function() {  
     container.isotope({ 
         filter: '*',
         itemSelector: '.isotope-item',
         animationOptions: {
             duration: 750,
             easing: 'liniar',
             queue: false,
         }
     }); 

     $('.project-filter a').click(function(){ 
         var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter'); 
   $('.project-filter li').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');         
         container.isotope({ 
             filter: selector,
             animationOptions: {
                 duration: 750,
                 easing: 'liniar',
                 queue: false,
             } 
         }); 
       return false; 
     });
 });
});
```

```html
//Build the filter navigation
        if ( $show_filter ) {
            $terms = get_terms('menus_category','orderby=name&hide_empty=0');            
            if ( count($terms) > 0 ) { 
                echo '<ul class="menu-filter"><li class="active"><a data-filter=".">' . esc_html__( 'Összes', 'zupa' ) . '</a></li>';                
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    $termname = strtolower($term->name);
                    $termname = str_replace(' ', '-', $termname);
                    echo '<li><a data-filter=".' . esc_attr( $termname ) . '" href="#" title="' . esc_attr( $term->name ) . '">' . esc_html($term->name) . '</a></li>';
                }
                echo '</ul>';//.food-filter
            }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please reduce your code to only to the part that displays your `links`/`menu`. That's seems to be the only part you need to show in relation to your problem.

Comment: Hey!
I updated it :)
Thnaks

Comment: and i added the js code too :)